# @firebase/database: Can't determine Firebase Database URL. Be sure to include a Project ID when calling firebase.initializeApp(). Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am in process of creating live chatroom
I succeded at it as first time I approached it all worked
But then I was in need to work on other task and when I am back on this, firstly I got the error which stated that I can init firebase twice, when I fixed this one, I got this error

Full error message:
[image: Error message]

`chatroom.component.ts`

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import "firebase/database";
import { AuthService } from 'src/app/services/auth.service';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-chatroom',
  templateUrl: './chatroom.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./chatroom.component.sass']
})
export class ChatroomComponent implements OnInit {

  items!: object;
  message: string = '';
  ref: any;

  constructor(
    private profileService: AuthService
  ) {
    console.log(firebase.apps)
    if (!firebase.apps.length) {

      firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: "blablabla",
        authDomain: "blablabla",
        databaseURL: "blablabla",
        projectId: "blablabla",
        storageBucket: "blablabla",
        messagingSenderId: "blablabla",
        appId: "blablabla"
      });
    }else {
       firebase.app();
    }

    this.ref = firebase.database().ref('messages');

    this.ref.on("value", (snapshot: any) => {
      console.log(snapshot.val());
      this.items = snapshot.val();
    });
  }


  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

  establishRoom(): void {

  }

  onSend(): void{
    this.ref.push().set({
      content: this.message,
    });

  }

}
```

config stuff spelling is checked several times (basically I copied them from Firebase web site)

error is triggered on that line `this.ref = firebase.database().ref('messages');`

working environment is Angular 11

Comment: is if (!firebase.apps.length) {}  resolving and running the  firebase.initializeApp() method? or is it running firebase.app()  and its being initialized elsewhere without the databaseURL or info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after digging the issue, it find out that for some reasons the default database was not the one I wanted to use.
so I ended up with this piece of code

```
firebase.app().delete().then(() => {

      firebase.initializeApp({
        apiKey: "...",
        authDomain: "...",
        databaseURL: "...",
        projectId: "...",
        storageBucket: "...",
        messagingSenderId: "...",
        appId: "..."
      });

      console.log(firebase.apps)

      this.ref = firebase.database().ref('rooms');

      console.log(this.ref)

    });
```

So I just deleting the default DB which I dont want and initializing the one I need

Answer (score 0):

The error is stating that it is having trouble consuming the databaseURL value from the [firebase app config](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup).

Should you need to acquire your firebase credentials again, you can find them through the [general settings](https://console.firebase.google.com/u/0/project/_/settings/general) page. Ensure that the key provided follows the correct format with the `PROJECT_ID` replaced with your own project id

`databaseURL: "https://PROJECT_ID.firebaseio.com"`

Additionally, if you are using obfuscation within your app, make sure it does not apply to these credentials